# How to stop warning for UIView may not respond to selector

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, compiler-warnings

I have a class that has a UIView as a property. Sometimes I pass in a UILabel; sometimes a UITextField. No matter which I pass in, I want the class to set the text. Currently I am doing this, which works:

```
if ([self.viewToUpdate respondsToSelector:@selector(setText:)] && !self.newAnswer)
    [self.viewToUpdate setText:[[self.choices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] text]];
```

The problem is, this gives a warning, because even though I'm checking `respondsToSelector`, Xcode doesn't know that my UIView will respond to `setText:`. How can I remove this warning?

I know that I can specifically check to see if it's a TextField or a Label, and then cast to a TextField or a Label, respectively, but this would be a pain, and if I ever have more types of views, I'd have to add a few more lines of code for each one.

I thought about creating my own protocol, and then having my class have id as the type for viewToUpdate... but of course UITextField and UILabel wouldn't conform to that protocol...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try just casting it as an id:

```
if ([self.viewToUpdate respondsToSelector:@selector(setText:)] && !self.newAnswer)
    [(id)self.viewToUpdate setText:[[self.choices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] text]];
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I didn't think of that. So simple! Although the (id) needs to be put on the second line, not the first.

Comment: You would do better to test the object to determine that it is of the class you expect it to be, then casting to that specific class, than casting directly to id.  At least then you would avoid a crash if self.viewToUpdate was ever a different class than it is now.

Comment: Ryan, since I am testing respondsToSelector; it shouldn't matter exactly what class viewToUpdate is. I just know it's a UIView that has a setText: method; I don't know what type of UIView it is; and I don't want to have to test for each type of UIView individually.