# Avoid "[superclass] may not respond to [selector]" warning without incurring LLVM's "Cannot cast 'super'" error

Tags: cocoa, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, llvm, superclass

I have the following code in an NSView subclass:

```
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(forwardingTargetForSelector:)]) {
        // cast to (id) to avoid "may not respond to selector" warning
        return [(id)super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];
    } else {
        [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:aSelector];
        return nil;
    }
}
```

In the first line, `return [(id)super ...` casts `super` to `id` because under the GCC compiler, this suppressed the warning that the superclass (NSView) may not respond to `forwardingTargetForSelector:`, as suggested in [answers such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340888/how-to-stop-warning-for-uiview-may-not-respond-to-selector/4340916#4340916).

However, when I switch to the LLVM compiler, this results in a "Cannot cast super" error.  Is there a correct way to modify my code so that I get neither the warning nor the error under both LLVM and GCC?

Comment: Really, gcc should throw an error when casting super to id. super is a structure which includes the object and superclass pointers, so using it as an id would cause a crash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare the selector in an interface-only category in your implementation file.

```
@interface NSView (FastForwarding)

- (id) forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)selector;

@end
```

Comment: Will that cause `[super respondsToSelector:@selector(forwardingTargetForSelector:)]` to return true, even if there isn't an implementation of `forwardingTargetForSelector:`?

Comment: No. respondsToSelector: acts by checking the class for a matching implementation. It does not know about category interfaces unless you implement them also.

Comment: I am having trouble applying this solution to a situation where I am overriding UINavigationController and creating a new NavigationBar Delegate method, 

`-(BOOL) navigationBar:(UINavigationBar*)bar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem*)item`

Previously I cast the call to the super like so:
`return [(id<UINavigationBarDelegate>)super navigationBar:bar shouldPopItem:item];`

However, as pointed out above, this doesn't work with LLVM.  Since this is a delegate, I am not sure how to apply the solution by @Ahruman.  Thanks